# How can a martingale be a density process?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbf P,\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\ge 0})$ be a filtered probability space, and let $\mathbf Q$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\ge 0})$ such that $\mathbf Q\ll\mathbf P$. Then it's well known that the 'density process'
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
Z_t:=\mathbf E^{\mathbf P}\left[\frac{d\mathbf Q}{d\mathbf P}\bigg|\mathcal F_t\right]
\end{equation}
is a $\mathbf P$-martingale (see, for instance, [[Jacod and Shiryaev, 2003, Theorem III.3.4]](https://books.google.com/books?id=mSD4CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA166&dq=Limit+theorems+for+stochastic+processes+%22The+P-martingale+Z+is+called+the%22&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKz_XYwovZAhXOqFkKHeGnDU0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Limit%20theorems%20for%20stochastic%20processes%20%22The%20P-martingale%20Z%20is%20called%20the%22&f=false)).

Now we consider the **inverse** problem, that is,

> under what condition a $\mathbf P$-martingale $\{Z_t\}$ can be the density process of some probability measure $\mathbf Q$ which is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mathbf P$?

I cannot find out the answer to the inverse problem in Jacod and Shiryaev's book. Can anyone give some comments or reference to it? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, $Z_t$ has to be a.s. positive and uniformly integrable. Then, it's convergent for $t\to\infty$ in $L^1$ to an a.s. positive $Z_\infty$, and $$Z_t=E(Z_\infty\mid\mathcal{F}_t).$$ Obviously, you can use $Z_\infty$ as the density you're looking for.
It's surprisingly difficult to find a reference, though. In the discrete case, it would be Theorem 4.5.6 in this [lecture](https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Spring2011/APM504/lectures/lecture27/lecture27.pdf). It's also Theorem T18 in Chapter V, §3 of "Probability and Potentials" by P. A. Meyer, but I own the Russian translation, so...

Comment: Thank you. I still got a question here. If $Z$ is a positive and uniformly integrable martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbf P,\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\ge 0})$, then it's easy to get that the measure $\mathbf Q:=Z_\infty.\mathbf P$ is the only measure on $\mathcal F_\infty:=\bigvee_{0\le t\le\infty}\mathcal F_t$ such that the equation (1) holds, by the [Caratheodory Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem). My question is if $\mathbf Q$ is unique on $\mathcal F$ satisfying (1)?

Comment: @Q. Huang If $\mathcal{F}$ is bigger than $\mathcal{F}_\infty$, $\mathbf Q$ can't be unique.